# PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: on rake db:reset

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

When execution `rake db:reset` I have the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "routes" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_0ed30cb49b"
DETAIL:  Key (planification_id)=(0) is not present in table "planifications".
```

Details of the error :

```
: INSERT INTO "routes" ("evite_autoroute", "places_disponibles", "duration", "distance", "price", "date_heure_aller", "mode_reservation", "modele", "taille_bagages", "detours", "flexibilite", "event_name", "event", "confort", "ladies_only", "men_only", "description_aller", "planification_id", "vehicule_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22) RETURNING "id"
/home/charles/cardating/web/db/seeds.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
```

I first thought it was a missing foreign key between Route and Planification, so I added `add_index :planifications, :route_id` on the migration file where the Planification table us created but it changed nothing.

Create Planification migration file :

```
class CreatePlanifications < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :planifications do |t|
      t.string :modele
      t.text   :jours

      t.belongs_to :route, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :planifications, :route_id
  end
end
```

Create Route migration file :

```
class CreateRoutes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :routes do |t|
      t.boolean :evite_autoroute
      t.integer :places_disponibles
      t.integer :distance
      t.integer :duration
      t.decimal :prix, precision: 3, scale: 2
      t.datetime :date_heure_aller
      t.datetime :date_heure_retour
      t.date :date_du
      t.date :date_au
      t.string :mode_reservation
      t.string :modele
      t.string :taille_bagages
      t.string :detours
      t.string :flexibilite
      t.string :event_name
      t.integer :delais_reponse
      t.boolean :event
      t.boolean :confort
      t.boolean :ladies_only
      t.boolean :men_only
      t.text :description_aller
      t.text :description_retour
      t.references :planification, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :vehicule, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.belongs_to :user, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In `CreateRoutes`, is this intentional: ` t.references :planification, index: true, foreign_key: true`? If yes, what's the purpose?

Comment: I am not the author of those migrations and i'm a noobie in rails so I don't fully understand what this code means

Comment: I find this usually happens when certain "dependent: :destroy" statements are missing in certain models that depend on eachother.  What this means is that there could be a record in your db that belonged to another record however that record has been deleted and so you now have an invalid key.  This error then only bubbles up when you touch that record.